# How to have multiple PCs accessible via SSH, and a single code base run in each independently

Tags: python, linux, ssh, command-line, terminal

There are a number of computer that I can access via ssh.

I was wondering if I can have a python code base in a single location but execute a part of it or all of it in each of these computers independently.

I can copy my codes in each of these PCs and then execute them in each through SSH but it will be hard then to make a change in the code since I should do it in all the copies.

I was also wondering if I can do something like this similar to a cluster since each of these PCs has a number of CPUs, though that would probably not be possible or very easy.

Comment: Two options quickly pop to mind:  1) Use `sshfs` to mount the remote code location to the local PC and run.  2) Use something like [git](https://git-scm.com/) to store your configured code, and setup each of the PCs to pull the app (?) from the remote code repo.  This way, you update / configure the code once and pull the update to each PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options quickly pop to mind:

1. Use `sshfs` to mount the remote code location to the local PC and run.
2. Use something like [git](https://git-scm.com/) to store your configured code, and setup each of the PCs to pull the app (?) from the remote code repo. This way, you update / configure the code once and pull the update to each PC.

**For example:**
We use the second method.  We have seven RasPi servers running various (isolated) tasks.  One of the servers is a NAS server which has a Git repo on it - where we store our configured code, and use `git pull` or `git clone` commands (via ssh) to pull the app to the local server.  Works really well for us.  Maybe an idea to help you ... ?

Comment: Thanks, this is by far the best solution I can think about. Thanks.

Comment: @AlirezaRanjbar - Excellent, hope it helps.  Can you please mark this as the accepted answer?  Thanks!